# Prime Power Divisibility and Wolstenholme Theorem

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

In A. Gardiner's paper: Four Problems on Prime Power Divisibility, Amer. Math. Monthly 95(1988),926-931, He said that ``A simple calculation then shows that (for $p\geq5$)''

$$1^{p-3}+2^{p-3}+\cdots+(p-1)^{p-3}\equiv\sum_{r=1}^{p-1}\frac{1}{r^2}\bmod p^2$$
I don't know how to get this congruent property, could any one explained this for me?

We know that for every integer $r\in\mathbf{Z}$, $p\nmid r$,
$$r^{p-3}\equiv \frac{1}{r^2}\bmod p$$
thus it is clear that
$$1^{p-3}+2^{p-3}+\cdots+(p-1)^{p-3}\equiv\sum_{r=1}^{p-1}\frac{1}{r^2}\bmod p$$
We also know that for $r\in\mathbf{Z}$,
$$r^{\varphi(p^2)}=r^{p^2-p}\equiv 1\bmod p^2$$
Hence
$$1^{p^2-p-2}+2^{p^2-p-2}+\cdots+(p-1)^{p^2-p-2}\equiv\sum_{r=1}^{p-1}\frac{1}{r^2}\bmod p^2$$
but I have no idea how to prove
$$1^{p-3}+2^{p-3}+\cdots+(p-1)^{p-3}\equiv\sum_{r=1}^{p-1}\frac{1}{r^2}\bmod p^2$$

Comment: For the case when $p=5$: Then is $1^2+2^2+3^2+4^2 \equiv 1+19+14+11 \pmod {25}$ according to your question?

Comment: @ChadShin You can think they all are $p$-adic integers and the congruence  are in the ring of $p$-adic integers $\mathbf{Z}_p$.

Comment: The point that I was trying to make was that the question is claiming that $1^ {p-3}+2^ {p-3}+\dots+(p-1)^{p-3} \equiv 1^{p^2-p-2}+2^{p^2-p-2}+\dots (p-1)^{p^2-p-2} \pmod {p^2}$ However, this is not true when $p=5$.

Comment: @ChadShin Yes, you are right, the congruence should be $$1^{p-3}+2^{p-3}+\cdots+(p-1)^{p-3}\equiv\frac{3}{2}\sum_{r=1}^{p-1}\frac{1}{r^2}\bmod p^2$$. You can find the congruence in Zhihong Sun's paper:http://www.hytc.edu.cn/xsjl/szh/ber1.pdf  p.206(5.1) and corollary 5.1.

Comment: @ChadShin I was also just realized that the congruence is wrong, I should compute it first in small cases. Professor Sun recommended me his paper a few minutes ago.